# como puedo guardar todos los datos de un DataGridView en un archivo txt en C#

Tags: c#, archivo, datagrid

Ya intente hacerlo pero solo me guarda la primera linea (la de los titulos) y necesito empezar a guardar de la segunda linea para abajo.

este es mi codigo:

```
private void btnguardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter escribirenTxt = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Archivos.txt", true);
    try
    {
        escribirenTxt.WriteLine(Column1.HeaderText + "," + Column2.HeaderText + "," + Column3.HeaderText + "," + Column4.HeaderText + "," + "\n");
        MessageBox.Show("Registrado Exitosamente, C:/Users/usuarios/Desktop/Archivos.txt");
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error al registrar...");
    }
    escribirenTxt.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usted puede hacerlo en este modo, it's a good practice también utilice la palabra clave en su panorama.

Este código se bucle su Grid y escribe el contenido en un archivo de texto, recuerde elegir las columnas y de lo que desea.

```
using (var writetext = new StreamWriter("C:\\temp\\write.txt"))
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvData.Rows)
    {
        writetext.WriteLine($"{row.Cells[0].Value}, {row.Cells[1].Value}, {row.Cells[2].Value}, {row.Cells[3].Value}" );
    }
}
```